# Как избежать ошибок KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c

В общем есть класс:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int online;
@property (nonatomic) int uid;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *last_name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *photo_200_orig;

@end
```

Заполняю его данными:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [responseObject objectForKey:@"response"]) {
     [user setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
}
```

Опасность состоит в том, что если на сервере "ключ" измениться, приложение будет вылетать, скажет "online" станет "user_online" на этом работа приложения закончиться, как можно обеспечить безопасность, что бы при другом ключе данные не записывались?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Как вариант заключить это дело (весь цикл) в @try @catch - от падения спасет

Comment: Оно то спасает, но тогда вот какая история, в AppStore есть приложение, на сервере меняется одно поле, и можно сказать пол приложения без данных, оно то не упадет, но и данных не будет, а ме нужно как-то сравнить поля, если такое есть то записать, если нету то не записывает и выйдет что лишь одно/два поля не будет с данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ещё так (суть такая же, как в первом примере [[@iFreeman](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)):

```
@interface ViewController () {
    User *user;
}

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [responseObject objectForKey:@"response"]) {
    user = [[User alloc] init];
    for (NSString *keys in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        if ([user respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(keys)]) {
            [user setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:keys];
        }
    }
}
```

**После цыкла:**

```
NSLog(@"%@", [user last_name]);
NSLog(@"%i", [user uid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

есть вариант проверки поддерживает ли объект сеттер, например:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [responseObject objectForKey:@"response"]) {
    for (NSString *key in dict.allKeys) {
        NSString *setterStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", [key capitalizedString]];
        if ([user respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(setterStr)]) {
            [user setValue:dict[key] forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

есть и более сложное, но куда более сильное - использовать Objective C Runtime API:

например что-то вроде:

```
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
     objc_property_t property = properties[i];
     const char *propName = property_getName(property);
     NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
     if (propertyName.length) {
         NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:propName
                                                                               encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
         [obj setValue:dict[propertyName] forKey:propertyName]; 
    }
}
free(properties);
```

обратите внимание, в первом примере мы лупимся по всем ключам в полученном JSON и ищем соответствующие им set методы в объекте, если находи - сетим значение, во втором - наоборот: мы берем все объявленные property объекта перебираем их и ищем их в полученно JSON. Оба метода делают примерно одно и то же.

В любом случае здесь вас ожидает еще одна проблема: если после какого-то апдейта сервер вдруг начнет отдавать вам вместо NSNumber NSString или наоборот, падение также будет неизбежно, но где-то потом, его будет уже несколько сложнее отловить. К тому же парсеры еще любят засунуть NSNull туда, где мы ожидаем скажем NSString, что тоже очень и очень плохо. Если у вас не так много данных, я бы рекомендовал все-таки проверять каждое значение по мере возможности конечно.

Comment: А что такое "someValue" в вашем примере?

Comment: исправил ответ, посмотрите, не someValue, а значение из словаря по ключу

Comment: Так всё номрально, только при прохождении цылка NSLog(@"%@", user.last_name);
выдает:
2014-03-06 23:33:07.055 eert[8378:70b] (null)

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что же это значит. Посмотрите, ключи в dict = responseObject[@"response"] соответствуют названиям пропертей в юзере? Если да, попробуйте NSLog setterStr, для поля last_name должно быть "setLast_name:" и проверьте проходит ли проверка на respondsToSelector:, если нет - дело в сигнатуре метода, нужно будет поправить как там правильно я довольно-таки на вскинку писал

Comment: @VladimirBabochin, Вы видимо забыли написать: user = [[User alloc] init];